# Retrieve audited entities name, old value and new value of the given revision

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-envers

I am using envers to audit a User class and it saving all modified data in DB with rev number. Now, i need to recover all edited entities name, old value and new value by passing revision number as parameter.

I have read envers doc but could not find any solution for it.

Can anyone please suggest? thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A revision number uniquely identifies a version of an entity, hence when getting an entity at a specific revision, you get it with the values it had back then.

To get the old and new values of fields, if you know the entity has been changed at revision `N`, the easiest way is to get the entity at revisions `N-1` and `N` and compare the fields you are interested in.

This can be done in a single query using the `forRevisonsOfEntity` query (see the `AuditReader` and `AuditQueryCreator` [javadocs](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/javadocs/))

Comment: thanks, but can you pls suggest how, i need to compare also.thanks

Comment: If we compare revision N and N-1, there is no guarantee we are comparing the same entity. Revision number is unique across all entities. Revision No with PK of that entity would be the key. So you need to find the earlier revision of same Pk and then compare those. Am I missing anything ?